# receiving a request failed error JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Experiencing problems with my javascript function. It returns a request failed server fault however still calls the php file fine and inserts the record in the database and refreshes the page to show the added record. No idea why its having this issue. Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

this is the jQuery:

```
function addPropCall() {
  var data = $('#addProposal').serialize();
  $.post('../Supervisor/Proposal_AddSubmit.php', data, function(response){

    $("#addProposal").html(response);
    // 'soft'reload parent page, after a delay to show message
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('#addPModal').modal('hide')
      location.reload();
    },3500);

  }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
  });
}
```

This is the form which gets serialized:

```
<div id="addPModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addPModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Add New Proposal: </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form id="addProposal" class="addProposal">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="code" class="control-label">Proposal ID:</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="proposal_id" name="proposal_id" readonly value ="NULL">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="title" class="control-label">Enter Proposal Title:</label>
                                    <textarea type="text" class="form-control input-xlarge" rows="2" id="proposal_title_id" name="proposal_title"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="title" class="control-label">Enter Proposal Description:</label>
                                    <textarea type="text" class="form-control input-xlarge" rows="7" id="desc_id" name="description"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <?php

                                include "../includes/db_conx.php";

                                try {

                                    $db_conx = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);

                                    $db_conx->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                                    $stmt3 = $db_conx->prepare('SELECT * FROM course_details ORDER BY course_title');
                                    $stmt3->execute();
                                    $courses = $stmt3->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                                }

                                catch(Exception $e)
                                {
                                    die ("Could not connect to the database $mysql_dbname :" . $e->getMessage());
                                }
                                ?>

                                <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addTModal" data-id="#">Select Tags  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tags"/></button> -->

                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="course_details">Select Course:</label><p></p>
                                    <select name="course">
                                        <option value=''>Select One</option>";
                                        <?php foreach($courses as $course): ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $course['course_code'] ?>"><?php echo $course['course_title'] ?></option>
                                    <?php endforeach ?>
                                </select>
                            </div> </p>

                            <?php

                            include "../includes/db_conx.php";

                            try
                            {

                                $db_conx = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);

                                $db_conx->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                                $stmt = $db_conx->prepare('SELECT * FROM tag_details ORDER BY tag_title ASC');
                                $stmt->execute();
    //$count = $stmt>rowCount();
                                $tags = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                            }
                            catch(Exception $e)
                            {
                                /*** if we are here, something has gone wrong with the database ***/
                                $e->getMessage();
                            }


                            ?>


                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="tag_details">Select Tags:</label><p></p>
                                <p class="text-danger"><small>(Select up to 3)</small></p>
                                <div class="checkbox-new">
                                    <?php foreach($tags as $tag): ?>

                                    <input name='tag[]' class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $tag['tag_code'] ?>"><?php echo $tag['tag_title'] ?></p>

                                <?php endforeach ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="user_token" value="<?php echo  $_SESSION['user_token'];  ?>"/>

                        <div class="modal-footer">

                            <div class="btn-toolbar">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" class="pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>


                                <button name= "addProp" value = "addProp" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="addPropCall();">Add Proposal</button>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Error:

[image: Error Message]

i know the php is fine because when i called the page directly using the 'method="post" and action attributes it was fine.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the submit button is submitting the page, you need to cancel the action.

```
onclick="addPropCall(); return false;">
```

---

Ideally you would be using jQuery to attach the events since that is a better practice than inline events.

```
$("[name='addProp']).on("click", addPropCall);
```

and you can use event.preventDefault()

```
function addPropCall (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //...
}
```

Comment: Ahh i see! missed such a little thing. I just changed the type="submit" to "button" and that has seemed to fix it. Thanks!